# Finding limit of sequence with basic rules

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find the limit of $(n^2-\sqrt{n^4-n^2+2})$ as $n$ approaches infinity with basic tools such as the laws of limits and L'Hôpital's rule.

I'm pretty much stuck at the fact that the limit of $n^2$ approaches infinity so distributing the limit wouldn't make sense.

How would one approach this kind of problem?

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by conjugate

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply by $1$ in a nice way:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(n^2-\sqrt{n^4-n^2+2}\right)\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n^4-n^2+2}}{n^2+\sqrt{n^4-n^2+2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2-2}{n^2+\sqrt{n^4-n^2+2}}$$

Can you take it from here?